# Alternatives to IP session binding

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, cookies

I'm not sure if the idea of binding IPs to sessions is a good one.

What are the alternatives?

Currently what I have is this:

- Browser sends session ID
- Server checks if session hasn't expired

But what if a third party somehow finds out the session ID? Should I care about this possibility? Binding the session to an IP would make such a session forgery more difficult, but there are cases when more than one user might appear with the same IP.

I'm clueless! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NEVER** write your own session handler,  use whatever comes with your platform.   Limiting to ip address not a good idea.  IP addresses change for legitimate reasons, such as if the user is behind a load balancer.   Further more,  what if they are a free wifi network?  Then everyone gets access.

Comment: I'm using PHP, and PHP has session handling, but since this is my first server-side scripting project, and I'm trying to learn how stuff works, I thought maybe writing session handling by myself would be a good way to learn how it works. Maybe I'm wrong? In any case, another user behind the same wifi network won't have the same cookies (unless he can intercept the connection, and I believe this can only be solved with SSL right?).

Comment: @Rook this answer doesn't make sense. what platform are you talking about?

Comment: @Steve  every web application platform worth its salt has a session handler because it would be completely useless without it.  The OP didn't say what platform he was using,  but he just posted PHP,  which has a fantastic session handler.

Comment: @Camilo Martin Yeah you are on the right track,  and your right about SSL.  Writing your own session handler is a great idea for educational purposes,  just never use it in a production system.   Basically a session ID should always be a "cryptographic nonce", this can be used to store state about a user in a database.   Try implementing your system using `set_cookie()` and `mysql_query()`.  In a production system always use `session_start()` and the `$_SESSION[]` superglobal.

Comment: @Camilo Martin Well you should understand that HTTP is stateless and why we need sessoin id's.  I personally haven't written one.  I learned by reading a lot of existing applications.  I recommended picking out an interesting application and reading through the code,  see how it handles sessions. Also try and modify the application.  If you get a debugger and step though the code you'll have an even better understanding of the programs flow.  When I am assigned a new project for my work the first thing I do is step though the code to figure out how its put together.

Comment: Thanks @Rook! I think I should leave session handling to PHP, since as you say every web platform has a built-in mechanism and I fear of reinventing the wheel instead of focusing on more important code.

Comment: @Rook: Although I agree with your statement about using the built in session handling for the given platform (+1); I disagree with your comment about a given platform being worthless without it.  We don't use session, haven't used it in years, and forcibly turn it off on every project we've done.  There are usually better ways

Comment: @Chris Lively What platform is this?  Because without a session handler then you can't allow people to login.  The worst part of not having a session handler is that people are just going to roll their own,  and invariably all applications for that platform will be very insecure.

Comment: @Chris this is my first server-side project and one of the first things I'm having to deal with is accounts (hence logins and sessions), so I can't understand how you've lived without them.

Comment: @Rook: asp.net 4/c#.  We don't utilize session at all because our stuff is generally running in a large farm.  "Sticky sessions" for load balancers aren't guaranteed (and we've seen them fail horribly) which means it has to be backed by a database or state server... which completely eliminates the benefits of using session in the first place.

Comment: @Rook,@Camilo: The thing to bear in mind is that session isn't some magical thing. It simply stores some pieces of data in memory on the web server.  That data can live anywhere: e.g. database, memcache, whatever. Where you store it should be determined by the time it takes to pull it from it's original source, # of machines that might need access to it, the nature in regards to whether used by multiple users or a single one, and whether it is static enough to be cached. Once you start looking at these factors session stops making sense on anything but simple single server sites.

Comment: @Chris I see, it makes sense that session handling wouldn't be as straightforward with multiple servers. Still, PHP seems to have a handy way to plug your own session storage mechanism and everything can be used just the same: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php don't know how it works in practice though, but it seems like if some site gets too big, implementing a separate session server would at least be a minor to moderate refactoring effort.

Comment: @Camilo: I think you missed my point.  People use session to store things locally to keep from going across the network wire to hit a database.  Once you scale out with multiple web servers, this means you have to move your session data to either a different server (additional point of failure) or store it back in a database... If you are already hitting a database to get this data in the first place, why store it in a different database which would result in the data being retrieved and saved on every page load..  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Chris I see, I guess the mechanics of sites with multiple servers are currently beyond me so I'll refrain from discussion in this matter.

Comment: @Rook: Yes you do and if you want to do session type work then I completely agree that you should leverage the built in provider, which is why I upvoted you ;).  I just thought it was important to point out that the OP should consider what limitations session actually has and make a decision as to whether it should be used to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to bind the user-agent instead of the IP for reasons stated above. Binding the user-agent makes it a little more difficult to replay the cookie.

SSL is great to prevent "Man-in-the-middle attack" but it's not a magic "secures it all" solution. If your website is vulnerable to XSS, the cookies are not safe (and by extension, the session id).

Also: watch out for session fixation.

Comment: -1 the user agent is an attacker controlled variable.  Thus by checking this value the security of the application remains unchanged.  Cookies can be protected from XSS via "http-only cookies",  however session riding (XSRF) and xss based session riding is still an issue.

Comment: XSS is something that should not happen in the first place, IMHO. I know it's bound to happen someday because it even happens with big guys, but it's not something I like to think that will happen with me. In any case, an user agent is easily spoofed, much easier than an IP. The attacker can copy the victim's UA just by getting him to visit a particular page or iframe.

Comment: @Camilo Martin Defense in depth,  security in layers.

Comment: @Rook I couldn't understand your statement :(